# Android app icon missing in recents but present everywhere else

Tags: android, android-studio

Like the title says, the app's icon is present in the launcher, in the settings app, and in App Info, but missing in the recent apps screen where it shows up like this instead:

[image]

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: does your manifest specify a different icon based on which activity is running...I know this is possible...may not be your issue but it might

Comment: in new OS this problem occur you can refresh your home screen launcher and restart your device

Comment: Yea restarting the emulator fixed it -- thanks @unzila

Comment: great u welcome :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's stupid -- but restarting the emulator fixes it. If your app icon is showing up everywhere else then it's not a problem with your app so don't worry about it.

Comment: I can confirm this. It was just a stupid emulator bug. Wasted hours recreating the icon.

Comment: I am having this issue on real device. Android 10. Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

use image assets to add icon launcher

[image]
[image]
[image]

this give u rounded icon
check your manifest to set rounded icon

```
  <application
    ...
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    ...>

      ....

  </application>
```

Comment: I am unable to find the option for Image Assets. I am using latest Android Studio on Linux, can you advise a solution?

Comment: @CapeAndCowl just right click on any directories in project app section, (like right click on res directory) go to first option ("New") you must see ("Image Asset")

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the emulator like what Adithya said or just clear storage the app. this will fix the problem.

Comment: Do you know why it would fix the problem?